# How to configure RDFWriter to explicit write data type in literals?

Tags: java, turtle-rdf, rdf4j

I'm saving a TTL file using `RDFWriter`.
How can I explicitly save literals with their data type?

For example, I want `"5.36289"^^xsd:float` but I get `5.36289E0` instead.

I had the same problem with strings, but I found the `BasicWriterSettings.XSD_STRING_TO_PLAIN_LITERAL` property that solved. I cannot find any similar configuration for other data types.

I am creating the literals using the method `Values.literal`.

This is the source code:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ttlOutputFile);
RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, out);

final WriterConfig config = writer.getWriterConfig();
config.set(BasicWriterSettings.XSD_STRING_TO_PLAIN_LITERAL, false);

writer.startRDF();

for (Statement st : model) {
    writer.handleStatement(st);
}
writer.endRDF();
```

Comment: As [per the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#abbrev), this is simply an abbreviated syntax, and parsing will include the datatype. Why do you want to avoid this syntax?

Comment: The problem arises because I need to load that dataset on a Python tool (that probably does not use a standard library) and it gives me an error if I inject a TTL with the extended syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration setting called `ABBREVIATE_NUMBERS` that works like a charm (and it needs to be used only when `PRETTY_PRINT` is true, which is the default value).

```
final WriterConfig config = writer.getWriterConfig();
config.set(BasicWriterSettings.PRETTY_PRINT, true);
config.set(BasicWriterSettings.XSD_STRING_TO_PLAIN_LITERAL, false);
config.set(TurtleWriterSettings.ABBREVIATE_NUMBERS, false);
```